# SQL Server 2005 Job - Call PLSQL procedure using connection string from registry

Tags: sql-server-2005, plsql, registry, connection-string, sql-server-job

I hope I am asking a reasonably easy question - just trying to save myself some time to be honest. :)

All I want is to call a PL/SQL procedure from a SQL Server job.

I already have the connection string in a registry string and I have the procedure built.

I dont know if I can just specify T-SQL and grab the registry setting somehow, but I suspect that I need an ActiveX script (if this is possible).

Does anyone have this (admittedly quite specific) code snippet handy?

Thanks in advance!

Frosty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got there in the end. This worked for me under an ActiveX job:

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

Dim oConnection, oRegistry, sConnectionString, sPlsqlCall, sRegistryKey, sValueName, sParam1, sParam2

' Get connection string from registry
Set oRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
sRegistryKey = "Software\OracleConnectionString"
sValueName = "Value"
oRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sRegistryKey, sValueName, sConnectionString

' Set up PLSQL query
sPlsqlCall = "my_package.my_procedure(" & sParam1 & ", " & sParam2 & ")"

' Call PLSQL
Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oConnection.ConnectionString = sConnectionString
oConnection.Open
oConnection.Execute sPlsqlCall

oConnection.Close
Set oConnection = Nothing
Set oRegistry = Nothing
```